# How to expand new EBS storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have added a new 2TB EBS volume to my database instance:

Volume Snapshot:

[image: Volume Snapshot]

I would like to merge the 2TB volume so that I can write a big dataset onto the database, but `growpart` and `resize2fs` don't seem to work.

I get this error:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 0
WARN: unknown label 
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/nvme0n1
sfdisk: /dev/nvme0n1: does not contain a recognized partition table
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/nvme0n1
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: What about resizing the root ebs volume and deleting the unused one?https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/ or `create a AMi image out of your current ec2 instance and using this aim image create a new ec2 instance with large storage directly'

Comment: What do you mean by "merge it"? merge to what? You can't marge it to your existing volume.  Either resize your 8GB volume to 2TB, or migrate your db to the new volume.